# Past perfect in "Stories conflict whether Joey and Linda had broken up prior to Linda dating Johnny", why?

Tags: past-perfect, past-simple

From the Wikipedia article on [Linda Ramone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linda_Ramone):

> #### Relationship with the Ramones
>
> Linda originally dated Joey Ramone but later dated and married Johnny Ramone. Stories conflict whether Joey and Linda **had broken up** prior to Linda dating Johnny or if Linda left Joey for Johnny.

Why *had broken up* should be "whether  Linda and Joey broke up before she dated with Johnny"? In this sentence what comes first the dating then the breaking up
that is the problem, I think! I have found the answer to my question: past perfect is used as something that had not arrived yet but was going to happen.

Comment: -1 for assuming any sentence in Wikipedia is going to use good grammar and/or style

Comment: @Clare "*-1 for assuming any sentence in Wikipedia is going to use good grammar and/or style*" <--- Hold on a minute, this person's a learner. More importantly aren't you a teacher who assumes that grammar advice on the Education First website is accurate? A severe case of kettles calling out pots.

Comment: @Clare - Worst justification for a downvote I've ever seen. The OP doesn't imply that Wikipedia is infallible. Moreover, we exhort users to [tell us where they've found a sentence that confuses them](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1084/so-you-found-a-sentence-or-phrase-why-you-should-cite-your-source); we shouldn't downvote them for doing so.

Answer (score 1):

The [past perfect](http://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/quick-grammar/past-perfect) **had broken up** establishes a sequence of two events in the past. It's not strictly necessary because **prior to** already establishes a sequence, but this is quite a complex sentence so the writer may have wanted to add emphasis by using past perfect as well.

If I were writing this, I would probably also use past perfect, but I would use **whether** rather than **if** to start the final clause.